# Unable to parse a date in the Finnish locale

Tags: java, android, date, locale

I'm trying to parse a Finnish date using the examples I've found here on Stack Overflow but I keep getting a parsing exception.

Here's my snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat dftFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", new Locale("fi", "FI"));
Date datDate = dftFormat.parse("25 syyskuu 2012");
```

The `DateFormat` characters seem to the same as the one in English so i'm wondering why this doesn't work.

Here's the [information about the Finnish locale](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/fi-FI/index.html).

Thanks.

Comment: That code works for me... what JRE are you using?

Comment: Not getting any exception. In sysout it prints `Tue Sep 25 00:00:00 IST 2012`

Comment: I'm developing an Android app. I think I have bot JDK 1.6 and JDK1.7 installed but if remember correctly, Android used the 1.6.

Comment: Here's my actual exception: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "25 syyskuu 2012" (at offset 3)`.

Comment: Have you tried it the other way round? To output a date in the Finnish locale? Mybe it's an issue with the locale not being available? (Wild guess)

Comment: Finnish locale is (at least officially) supported since Android 2.3, maybe you're using a previous version? See supported ones [here](http://colincooper.net/blog/2011/02/17/android-supported-language-and-locales/)

Comment: My minimum SDK version is a set to AP113. I'm targeting only devices above 4.0.3 in which case it should be supported.

Comment: Ok, try the thing suggested by @Fildor then - try the other way around and update to question what happens.

Comment: @eis, I tried what you and @Fildor suggested and it worked. I was able to print out the date in the correct format. I even managed to parse the date. it seems that all Finnish dates end with a `ta` i.e. `syyskuu` becomes `syyskuuta`. The locale reference that I gave was wrong. If you see that link, you'll notice that the `ta` is missing.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla he, I'm actually Finnish myself, and still didn't think of that one. Glad it worked. "syyskuuta" would literally translate to "of September". Outside java world the date is actually written "25. syyskuuta", without the dot it has a different meaning... oh, well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that all Finnish dates end with a ta i.e. `syyskuu` becomes `syyskuuta`.

The locale reference that I gave was wrong. If you see that link, you'll notice that the `ta` is missing and that was some misleading information. I couldn't find the exact locale information for the Finnish locale in the Javadocs.

I learnt a lesson, thanks to @Eis and @Fildor, print out the date using your parsing format to see what the resultant string is. Then you can compare whether your input string is parseable using the format.

Here's how I tested my code:

```
Date datDate = dftFormat.parse("25 syyskuuta 2012");
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").format(datDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Both `syyskuu` and `syyskuuta` are correct spellings of `September` in Finnish. The first is for standalone use, the second for use in context.

The [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum can provide either form of spelling.

## java.time

I tried this same kind of code using the modern java.time classes rather than the old outmoded `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` classes.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### Formatted String of date value

For this example we instantiate a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for September 25, 2012 per the Question.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of ( 2012 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 25 );  // 2012-09-25
```

We get a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) to automatically localize when generating a String. Calling [`ofLocalizedDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) means our String will represent only the date portion of the date-time value. The [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) controls the length of the String (full, long, medium, short).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.LONG );
```

Next we replace the assignment of our [JVM’s current default `Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault--) with the [Finland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finland) & [Finnish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_language) locale. This [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) object determines two things: (a) the human language used to translate pieces such as name of day or name of month, and (b) the cultural norms for abbreviating, ordering elements such as month or date first, use of commas versus periods, and so on.

```
Locale locale = new Locale ( "fi" , "FI" );
formatter = formatter.withLocale ( locale );
```

Use that formatter to actually generate a `String` to represent our `LocalDate` value.

```
String output = ld.format ( formatter );  // 25. syyskuuta 2012
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "ld: " + ld + " with locale: " + locale + " | output: " + output );
```

> 25. syyskuuta 2012

As shown in the [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12603731/642706), java.time agrees that `syyskuuta` is the name of the month for September.

## Month name for display

The java.time classes include the [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). This handy class has a feature for generating a String with the name of the month localized to a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

This localization is a similar to idea to the localization we saw in code above. But what is different is the use of a different enum to control the length of the text. Here the [`TextStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) enum (rather than [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html)) offers full, narrow, and short… but also “standalone” versions of those three lengths. In some languages there is a difference in the word used when the text is used alone, as opposed to in a complete date. Just for fun, let's try that with Finnish.

```
Locale locale = new Locale ( "fi" , "FI" );
EnumSet<TextStyle> styles = EnumSet.allOf ( TextStyle.class );

for ( TextStyle style : styles ) {
    System.out.println ( style + " | " + Month.SEPTEMBER.getDisplayName ( style , locale ) );
}
```

### Mystery solved: Standalone month name

Sure enough, the output below explains the mystery. In Finnish:

- When using the month name alone, drop the `ta` for `syyskuu`.
- When used within the context of a specific date-time value include the `ta` for `syyskuuta`.

> FULL | syyskuuta
>
> FULL_STANDALONE | syyskuu
>
> SHORT | syyskuuta
>
> SHORT_STANDALONE | syys
>
> NARROW | S
>
> NARROW_STANDALONE | S

If you cannot control the improperly formatted inputs to your app, you could search-and-replace any standalone value with its proper version. Or perhaps you could use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) to expect the standalone version (I do not know if this is possible, just a thought).